# Carousel Language of Batflat CMS

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, carousel

We just tried to prepare a website with Batflat CMS.
So as you can see at http://www.gastronomist.com.tr.
There is a Carousel slider in Turkish. (added with  {$carousel.ana-sayfa-slider} )

```
{include: themes/".$settings.theme."/inc/header.html
<!-- Header Carousel -->
{$carousel.ana-sayfa-slider}
<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            {if: $bat.notify}
            <div id="notify" class="alert alert-{$bat.notify.type}">{$bat.notify.text}</div>
            {/if} {$page.content}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{include: themes/".$settings.theme."/inc/footer.html}
```

How can I add different carousel for different language? I checked https://batflat.org/docs but it didn't help.

Maybe you can help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I realize that there is Templates section at setting of each page.
Some kind of wordpress, it is possible to customize whatever you want.